# How can I fix a pointer error in C?

Tags: c

I am starting to learn about pointers in C.

How can I fix the error that I have in function `x()`?

*This is the error:*

```
Error: a value of type "char" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *".
```

*This is the full source:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void x(char **d, char s[]) {
    d = s[0]; // here i have the problem
}

void main() {
    char *p = NULL;
    x(&p, "abc");
}
```

Comment: This question keeps changing in subtle ways that make the comments not-quite accurate anymore.

Comment: The program in your latest edit has no errors, just a warning. It does have a bug if you are planning on using `p`.

Comment: Up to 4 edits now changing the example source code. This is a moving target!

Comment: @PeteBaughman yahh im sorry, you are right, i change the source a little bit for how it shuld be. the source not will change anymore.

Comment: Delete the offending line - seriously, if you don't tell us what you **want to do**, we can't help.

Comment: @BrianCain I believe `'a'` is an expression of type `int`.

Comment: you want to copy only first element in string array to d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `x()` you pass `d` which is a `char **` (a pointer to a string pointer), and `char s[]` (an array of `char`, passed as similarly to a pointer to `char`).

So in the line:

```
d = s[0];
```

`s[0]` is a `char`, whereas `char **d` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. These are different, and the compiler is saying you cannot assign from one to the other.

However, did your compiler *really* warn you as follows?

> `Error: a value of type "char" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"`

Given the code sample, it should have said `char **` at the end.

I *think* what you are trying to make `x` do is copy the address of the string passed as the second argument into the first pointer. That would be:

```
void x(char **d, char *s)
{
    *d = s;
}
```

That makes `p` in the caller point to the constant `xyz` string but does not copy the contents.

If the idea was to copy the string's contents:

```
void x(char **d, char *s)
{
    *d = strdup(s);
}
```

and ensure you remember to `free()` the return value in `main()`, as well as adding `#include <string.h>` at the top.

Comment: yahh you understand me. i shuld implement the strcpy(). but i know that the strcpy() function, do the copy one by enother.

Comment: `strcpy` is only needed if you are trying to copy the *content* of the string, rather than merely the pointer to it. If (say) the string gets modified later, there is a significant difference. Which is right depends on which you are trying to do. As you are learning about pointers, it's key you understand the difference. In any case, if you are copying the string's *contents* with a library function, just use `strdup()`.

Answer (score -2):

A more proper way would be to use `strcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void x(char **d) {
    *d = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));        
    strcpy(*d, "abc");
}

int main() {
    char *p;
    x(&p);
    printf("%s", p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs: abc

Comment: -1 for hardcoding `5`, ah, and BTW, sizeof(char) == 1

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: that's because you only allocate for the actual characters, but a string also contains a special terminator character and you need space for that as well.

Comment: jesus. let me rephrase: -1 for hardcoding a constant.

Comment: Wells thats a stupid reason to downvote, especially if we already know the length of the string (3 chars + null character)

Comment: Your program has a memory leak. Furthermore the main function returns int and not void.

Comment: If you want to copy the string, simply use `strdup()`.